# Get a tuple from lists with zip() in Python

Tags: python, tuples, zip

I'm stuck in this code, I have to get a tuple from three lists by using the zip function and a for loop (no index or enumerate (mandatory)). I need to get this:

```py
answer = (
    ("John", "London", "Cloudy"),
    ("Bruno", "San Paulo", "Sunny"),
    ("Mike", "Sevilla", "Windy"),
)
```

And I tried this (inside a function):

```py
answer = []
for item in zip([name], [place], [weather]):
    answer.append(item)
    answer = tuple(answer)
    return answer
```

The thing is, I'm getting this output:

```
((["John", "Bruno", "Mike"], ["London", "San Paulo", "Sevilla"], ["Cloudy", "Sunny", "Windy"]),)
```

So, not only the brackets inside are a problem but also the order. Can someone give a hint? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you putting the variables inside `[]`?

Comment: I tried eliminating them, and I get only the first "row" correctly, but couldn't make ir after

Comment: because you have `return answer` inside the loop, so you return after processing the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `[]` around the variables. Now you're zipping those lists, not the contents of the variables.

Just use:

```
answer = tuple(zip(name, place, weather))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this:

```
tuple(zip(name, place, weather))
(('john', 'london', 'cloudy'), ('bruno', 'san paulo', 'sunny'), ('mike', 'sevilla', 'windy'))
```